# Сериализация c# windows form

Tags: сериализация

есть форма, в которой надо ввести данные слева, и по нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить данные в формате XML" они сохранялись бы в XML файл, т.е сереализовывались, а по нажатии на кнопку "Загрузить данные из формата XML" показывались в текстбоксе ниже. Так же вот код, который я написал что бы понять что такое сереализация и как она работает(можно как то его изменить под то что мне надо), не могу теперь разобраться как сделать так, что бы я мог использовать данные, которые заполнил слева и сохранил в формате XML, а не так как они у меня заполнены просто в коде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто.

Воту Вас есть слева много текстовых полей, выпадушек и радио-кнопок.

Вы хотите, чтобы то, что "накликал" пользователь - сохранитлось в ОБЪЕКТЕ ДАННЫХ. Вот после этого можно этот объект данных сохранить.

Чтобы это было так - надо сделать вот что: по нажатию кнопочки "Сохранить данные" должен отработать код, который берет текстовое поле "Фамилия" и сохраняет его содержимое в поле объекта "SecondName", и точно то же самое делает со всеми другими контролами на странице.

А потом можно этот объект данных, куда уже записаны все эти строчки и цифры, записать на диск в вижде XML.

Вообще говоря, вторая часть Вашей задачи - это при чтении данных (ваша вторая кнопка) восстановить все надписи и положения кнопок в левой части.

Есть такая штука, как DataBinding. Она немного упрощает эту обезьянью работу "взять данные из полей-радо кнопок и дропдаунов и записать их в объект данных". Но особо на него не рассчитывайте, по настоящему это "выстрелило" только в WPF - приложениях.

Вроде всё объяснил :-)